# insufficient account keys for instruction

Tags: solana-program

My Solana program:

```
/// Define the type of state stored in accounts
#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub struct GreetingAccount {
    /// number of greetings
    pub counter: u32,
}

// Declare and export the program's entrypoint
entrypoint!(process_instruction);

// Program entrypoint's implementation
pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey, // Public key of the account the hello world program was loaded into
    accounts: &[AccountInfo], // The account to say hello to
    _instruction_data: &[u8], // Ignored, all helloworld instructions are hellos
) -> ProgramResult {

    // Iterating accounts is safer than indexing
    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

    // Get the account to say hello to
    let account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    msg!("Hello World Rust program entrypoint, param {}",account.owner);
    // // The account must be owned by the program in order to modify its data
    if account.owner != program_id {
        msg!("Greeted account does not have the correct program id");
        return Err(ProgramError::IncorrectProgramId);
    }

    // Increment and store the number of times the account has been greeted
    let mut greeting_account = GreetingAccount::try_from_slice(&account.data.borrow())?;
    greeting_account.counter += 1;
    greeting_account.serialize(&mut *account.data.borrow_mut())?;

    msg!("Greeted {} time(s)!", greeting_account.counter);

    Ok(())
}
```

client:

```
fn main() -> Result<()> {
    reg_log().expect("reg log fail");

    let keypair = Keypair::read_from_file("wallet-keypair.json").expect("key pair read fail");

    info!("use keypair pubkey: {}", keypair.pubkey());
    use_smart_contract(&keypair)?;

    Ok(())
}
fn gen_rpc() -> RpcClient {
    RpcClient::new("https://api.devnet.solana.com".to_string())
}
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct GreetingAccount {
    /// number of greetings
    pub counter: u32,
}
fn use_smart_contract(keypair: &Keypair) -> Result<()> {
    let rpc_client = gen_rpc();
    let recent_blockhash = rpc_client.get_latest_blockhash().unwrap();
    let program_id = Pubkey::from_str("GmE2x6UvSaZ5hcC6Y9LrzvXcR8yJHVsJe94aBbKjSDmc")?;

    let account = GreetingAccount { counter: 3 };

    let ix = instruction::Instruction::new_with_bincode(
        program_id,
        &account,
        vec![AccountMeta::new(keypair.pubkey(), true)],
    );
    let tx = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
        &[ix],
        Some(&keypair.pubkey()),
        &[keypair],
        recent_blockhash,
    );

    let signature = rpc_client.send_and_confirm_transaction(&tx);

    match signature {
        Ok(sig) => {
            println!("Transaction confirmed. Signature: {:?}", sig);
        }
        Err(err) => {
            println!("Transaction failed. Error: {:?}", err);
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

macro msg!:

```
1: Program GmE2x6UvSaZ5hcC6Y9LrzvXcR8yJHVsJe94aBbKjSDmc invoke [1]
2: Program log: Hello World Rust program entrypoint, param 11111111111111111111111111111111
3: Program GmE2x6UvSaZ5hcC6Y9LrzvXcR8yJHVsJe94aBbKjSDmc consumed 2779 of 200000 compute units
4: Program GmE2x6UvSaZ5hcC6Y9LrzvXcR8yJHVsJe94aBbKjSDmc failed: insufficient account keys for instruction
```

issue:

1. The program calls account.owner, which is not my wallet address.
2. Comment out 'if account.owner = Program_ID' shows the tip 'insufficient account keys for instruction'.

Where exactly did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3):

There might be some missing info here, because based on just this transaction and the code, this should fail on:

```
        msg!("Greeted account does not have the correct program id");
        return Err(ProgramError::IncorrectProgramId);
```

Since the output shows an owner of `11111111111111111111111111111111`, which is not your program id.

Either way, to make this work, you'll need to do two things:

- "create" the account on `keypair`, by allocating it enough space and assigning it to your program id. You can do this by prepending the following instruction:

```
system_instruction::create_account(
    payer_pubkey,
    keypair.pubkey(),
    rpc_client.get_minimum_balance_for_rent_exemption(std::mem::size_of::<GreetingAccount>()),
    std::mem::size_of::<GreetingAccount>(),
    &program_id,
)
```

- use another account as the fee payer on the transaction, since you can't use accounts belonging to another program. You can create another keypair and fund it with some lamports to pay for the rent-exemption on the account and also the transaction fee.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try it again